# Layout breaks when a block is "expanded" by increasing its padding & applying negative margin

Tags: css, css-float, margin

Kind of hard to put into words, so [here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMXLz/3/) showing it.

When hovering over one of the green blocks, I wanted its background to expand enough that it "touches" the contiguous rectangles (it overlaps their margins). However, when hovering over the last block of each line, the layout goes wild: the line below only shows one element, etc.

The cause seems to stem from the negative margin; since, if the margin for the "expanded" class is set to plain 0 instead of -5, this problem doesn't happen. But of course this would leave a space between blocks.

The size of the parent container doesn't seem to alter this. Note that for now I'm not particularly concerned about the fact that the expanded block isn't well centered and makes the others in its line wobble a bit, although it may be linked to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change de padding of the extended into 10px
http://jsfiddle.net/TMXLz/4/

Comment: Excellent. So it was more of a "I don't know how to count" problem on my part... ouch.

Comment: :) happens to everyone, glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do what you want is to position each of those blocks absolutely (position:absolute) into the place you want them. You're main issue here is that the changes you want to make to the box are going to cause them to encroach on each others space. So you either need to adjust all their spacing (using js) on each mouseover (which sucks). Or absolutely position the items into place (specific positioning style for each box) then you won't have an issue with them overlapping partially. Just be sure to increase the active ones z-index so its always 'over' the others.

Comment: @Gijs is definitely simpler, but I personally have never been a fan of negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the output you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/TMXLz/5/